# How to add custom build options to app.json

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I have 2 index pages: the usual one index.html and indexChrome.html. I would like to add custom build options to app.json to make Sencha Touch to use the second file for my custom build. I tried:

```
"builds": {
    "web": {
        "default": true
    },
    "native": {
        "packager": "phonegap",
        "phonegap" : {
            "config": {
                "platform": "android",
                "remote":true,
                "id": "com.company.myapp",
                "name" : "MyApp"
            }
        }
    },
    "chrome": { // <-- here I would like my custom options if possible
        "indexHtmlPath": "indexChrome.html"
        "buildPath": "googlechromeapp" // <-- I know it's not valid, but is there a way to change the build path here somehow too?
    }
 }
```

And then use "sencha app build chrome" command, but it's not working. How to accomplish this?

Comment: so you want separate build for index.html and indexChrome.html?

Comment: what Sencha Cmd are you using?

Comment: @Mohit yep, I would like to be able to build using another index html and folder for this build.

Comment: @olegtaranenko 6.0.0.202